# Access the key and value of php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is a response from a post request and i would like to access both the key and value

This is the code

```
$arrs = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
foreach($arrs as $index=>$arr){
 var_dump($arr["items"][ $index]);
   //die() to see the first response
 }
```

Now the above generates

```
array(1) {

     [11]=>string(3) "dfd"  //how do i get the 11 key

 }
```

I would like to get 11 and "dfd" above so that i can then use them eg

```
$model->username = $arr["items"][ $index]//use dfd .. so my $model->username="dfd"
$model->like = $arr["items"][ $index]//use 11 .... so my $model->like =11
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: Or `list($key, $val) = each($somearray);`

Comment: Awesome $keyval=key(array )  then i can easily use the $keyval to get the value

Comment: @AbraCadaver Please post your comments as an answer.  At your level of rep points, I am surprised that this needs to be said.  GEOFFREYMWNGI obviously found them useful (assuming those upvotes were from him).  Let's not leave resolved questions unanswered.